# Fetching Pinterest - dealing with AJAX/Javascript autoload

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web-scraping, pinterest

While scrolling pinterest for [whatever query](http://pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=mountains) , pictures pops up automatically. Otherwise don't.

Which is the best approach to fetch them in PHP ?
I mean, I must probably reproduce that "scrolling event" somehow to fetch the whole content for a certain query.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and Ajax.

Find the percentage that the user has scrolled down the page (see: http://iwearshorts.com/blog/measuring-user-scroll-with-jquery/)

Then use AJAX to call your PHP file and retrieve more content, and then use jQuery again to append it to the bottom of the div you want it to appear in.